# visual studio 2013 http error 404, url rewritten

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-8

my solution has been working fine up until today, and most of it still works except for a single page, which is a default.aspx page. I get a "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".

The URL has been rewritten from '~/Staff/Default.aspx', to '~/Staff/Default', and I have no idea why. If I retype in the '.aspx' on the end, it still gets taken off.

Detailed Error information:
Module: IIS Web Core,
Notification: MapRequestHandler ,
Handler: StaticFile,
Error Code: 0x80070002, 
Requested URL: http://localhost:50742/Staff/Default,
Physical Path: C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\etc\etc\Staff\Default, 
Logon Method: Negotiate

Other pages work, e.g. '~/Booking/Default.aspx' works fine, as do other similar directories with default pages in, but not this one. I don't have routing or any rewrites set up, and yesterday I had it working.
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: try to clear temp folder, close and reopen your project may solve your issue.

Comment: tried that, it's still rewriting the url. Just on that page apparently.

Comment: Oh then url rewriting must be there in your code, review your changes again and see where it gets redirection , also if your code is published, you can check online if the page has redirection or not.